# If the SDE of an Ito process is identically zero, are the drift and volatility both identically zero?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

If the Ito process $\mathrm{d}X_{t}=\mu(X_{t})\mathrm{d}t+\sigma
(X_{t})\mathrm{d}W\equiv0$, it seems that $\mu(X_{t})=0$ and $\sigma(X_{t}%
)=0$. Is it true? If yes, how to prove? We know that $\mathrm{d}X_{t}%
=\mu(X_{t})\mathrm{d}t+\sigma(X_{t})\mathrm{d}W\equiv0$ exactly means given time $s$ with $X_{s}\neq0$
$$
\forall u>s\qquad0\equiv X_{u}-X_{s}=\int_{s}^{u}\mu(X_{t})\,\mathrm{d}%
t+\int_{s}^{u}\sigma(X_{t})\,\mathrm{d}W_{t}%
$$
then $\mu(X_{t})\equiv0$ and $\sigma(X_{t})\equiv0$ for $s<t<u$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is true whether $X_{s}=0$ or not

Remark: If $\int_{s}^{x}f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t=0$ for any $x>s$, then
$f(x)=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(  \int_{s}^{x}f(t)\,\mathrm{d}%
t\right)  =\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(0)=0$

For $X_{t}=X_{s}$ is constant for any $t>s$, the [quadratic variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_variation#It.C3.B4_processes) is zero
$$
0=[X_{t}]=\int_{s}^{u}\sigma^{2}(X_{t})\,\mathrm{d}t
$$
which means $\sigma(X_{t})=0$. And for any $u>s$
$$
\int_{s}^{u}\mu(X_{t})\,\mathrm{d}t=(X_{u}-X_{s})-\int_{s}^{u}\sigma
(X_{t})\,\mathrm{d}W_{t}=0-0=0
$$
thus $\mu(X_{t})=0$.

Answer (score 0):

No, $X_t-X_0=0$ does, in general, not imply $\sigma=\mu=0$. Consider for instance the SDE

$$dX_t = X_t \, dt + X_t \, dW_t, \qquad X_0 := 0.$$

You can easily check that $X_t := 0$ solves the SDE, but the coefficients $\sigma(x) = \mu(x)=x$ are not identically zero.

Comment: I add $X_{0}\neq0$ now, then, is it true?

Comment: @ChenDeng-Ta No....

Comment: your example is not correct, for if $X_{t}\equiv0$, then $\mu(X_{t}
)=\sigma(X_{t})=X_{t}=0$.

Comment: @ChenDeng-Ta My example is correct... I guess you didn't state your problem correctly.